# CodenameOne - how to catch HTTP 404 error using Terse REST API

Tags: codenameone

How can I catch an HTTP 404 error using the Terse REST API in CodenameOne? At the moment the default error handler gets this but I would like to display my own message instead. The code I am using is fine if the accountNo exists and I can deal with the resulting JSON, but if not I get the standard error handler displaying the 404 error:

```
Response<Map> jsonData = Rest.get( URL + "lookup").
          jsonContent().
          queryParam("account",accountNo).
          getAsJsonMap();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be a mistake in that version of the method. It should fail silently without a UI Dialog. We'll fix it for the next update.

Notice that `jsonData` should have the error response code within it as `jsonData.getResponseCode()`.